# Beginner: Autocomplete not working?

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc, autocomplete

I'm trying to create a autocomplete textbox.
This is what I have in view
    @model .....
    @{
        ViewBag.Title = "Create";
        Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
        
    }

```
@using(Html.BeginForm("Action","Controller"))
{
   @Html.TextBoxFor(m=>m.myEmail)
}

@section Scripts{
    @Scripts.Render("~/Scripts/jquery-ui-1.10.4.min.js")

    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(function() {
            $("#myEmail").
                autocomplete({
                        source: '/App/Per',
                        minLength: 1,

                    }
                );   
        });

    </script>
}
```

When I type lets say `s` in textbox a request is sent to this method in controller

```
public JsonResult Person(string term)
{
    var persons = FindPersons(term,"bk@hello.com","bk").ToArray();
    var fullnameList = persons.Select(person => person.FirstName + " " + person.LastName).ToList();
    return Json(fullnameList, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
```

in browser when I inspect the element in chrome and check the `response` i get the values, for example

```
0: "Person1"
1: "Person2"
2: "Person3"
3: "Person4"
```

**Problem**

My autocomplete box doesn't fill up with these data. Wasn't i supposed to get a listbox thingy at the bottom of the textbox with above names?

**Edit 2:** *Generated HTML*

```
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Create - My ASP.NET Application</title>
    <link href="/Content/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="/Content/site.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

    <script src="/Scripts/modernizr-2.7.1.js"></script>


</head>
<body>

                <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse">
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                </button>
                <a class="navbar-brand" href="/">Date Picker</a>

            <div class="navbar-collapse collapse">
                <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                    <li><a href="/">Home</a></li>
                    <li><a href="/Home/About">About</a></li>
                    <li><a href="/Home/Contact">Contact</a></li>
                </ul>
                    <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
        <li><a href="/Account/Register" id="registerLink">Register</a></li>
        <li><a href="/Account/Login" id="loginLink">Log in</a></li>
    </ul>

    <div class="container body-content">

    <link href="/Content/themes/base/minified/jquery-ui.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>


<h2>Create</h2>
<form action="/App/Cr" method="post"><input id="myEmail" name="myEmail" type="text" value="" /></form>


    </div>

    <script src="/Scripts/jquery-2.0.3.js"></script>

    <script src="/Scripts/bootstrap.js"></script>
<script src="/Scripts/respond.js"></script>


    <script src="/Scripts/jquery-ui-1.10.4.min.js"></script>


    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(function() {
            $("#myEmail").
                autocomplete({
                        source: '/App/Per',
                        minLength: 1,

                    }
                );   
        });

    </script>
```

Comment: Is there an error in the Javascript console that you can share?

Comment: Is your refrences of js are properly added?

Comment: No javascript error, I'll take a screenshot of what files are being loaded in browser. Just a min

Comment: Have you also referenced a CSS theme file for jQuery UI?

Comment: @TiesonT. No I haven't, may be thats the problem. Where should I reference it? at the end or right after my jquery-ui.js part?

Comment: No, CSS links should be in the `<head>` whenever possible.

Comment: @TiesonT.  added css, still not working i added the minified version of jquery ui, u can check the picture

Comment: Well, you're not really using `Scripts.Render` correctly, unless that is the actual name you gave your bundle. Can you post the generated HTML?

Comment: @TiesonT. added generated HTML as edit 2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nothing looks particularly off (aside from the CSS link being misplaced). You might want to try formatting your JSON a bit differently, which would also have the effect of answering your last question.

Instead of this:

```
public JsonResult Person(string term)
{
    var persons = FindPersons(term,"bkc@example.com","bk").ToArray();
    var fullnameList = persons.Select(person => person.FirstName + " " + person.LastName).ToList();
    return Json(fullnameList, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
```

Try using:

```
public JsonResult Person(string term)
{
    var persons = FindPersons(term,"bk@example.com","bk").ToArray();

    return Json(persons.Select(p => new { label = p.FirstName + " " + p.LastName, value = p.Email }), JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
```

This is one of the results the API says the widget will work with: http://api.jqueryui.com/autocomplete/#option-source

Comment: So, my hunch was more or less correct: the widget wasn't parsing your JSON correctly. Seems odd, but c'este le vie.